# distinct date mysql php year

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have problem with my php/mysql.
I want to get distinct year from my fields ex 2013-06-20.
Now I get something like this :

```
2014
2013
2014
2013
2013
2014
2014
2014
2014
2014
2014
2014
```

PHP CODE :

```
<?$chuj=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT date_issue FROM invoices_sales ");
     while($chuje=mysql_fetch_object($chuj)){
        $test=explode("-",$chuje->date_issue);
       print_r($test['0']."<br>");
    }
    ?>
```

How I can get only once 2013 or 2014 year ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to grab the year from that particular date string.

```
SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(date_issue) FROM invoices_sales
```

This will ensure it's only comparing the year, as it stands, each of those strings likely have different dates, so it is evaluating the entire date as opposed to only the year.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $chuj=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(`date_issue`) as `yr` FROM `invoices_sales`");
    while($chuje=mysql_fetch_object($chuj)) {
        $test = $chuje->yr;
        print_r($test['0'] . "<br>");
    }
?>
```